# iPhone shows Question mark (in place of its icon) on connecting to the Mac

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, organizer

I have a (dev) build for the iPhone App & I need to install it on the iPhone that has been given to me.

Now, I have added the iPhone as a device to the provisioning profile for the App.

But, When I connected the iPhone to my mac, Question mark appears in place of its icon (in XCode > Windows > Organizer). And the options under the device are limited to Device Logs and Screenshots.

And on right hand side detail appears : **"The version of iOS on “iPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here."** Which clearly means that ihave to update my iOS SDK for the XCode that I am using.

Is there any way to do, like without updating the XCode for latest iOS SDK, I can install the App to the iPhone provided to me ???

Comment: No Krishna, I think you need to update your Xcode to your Phone's level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just build the app, and locate the .ipa file from the products. Then drag the ipa file into itunes and then sync it to your device.

Comment: @KingofBliss ..man that will be a cool feature..but i tried it..where do you drop the .ipa in iTunes..i dragged into it..but iTunes didn't picked it up

Comment: @Shubhank It will be add into Apps category in itunes

Comment: @Krishna Then add the ipa to itunes, also add the provisional profile so that it will be installed into your device

Comment: let me try, as you suggested, I will try it on windows too, as this way is using iTunes, hence no dependency on platform (ie, windows or mac, whatever)

Answer (score 0):

**If you have got the Xcode project..then you would have to update Xcode..that is the only solution..**

but if you got the build in .ipa format.then you should register your device on [www.testflightapp.com](http://www.testflightapp.com) and then transfer that ipa from there to your device..

Comment: I am supposed to use none of the third party tool, and also, i need to create "How to" document after this task, i need to make it simpler as possible. As it can be passed to anyone after me, he/she would find it easier. I think the best option is one n only, update XCode.

Comment: if you have goth .ipa then the solution is only testfilightapp.com..if you got code..then you should update Xcode.